# SQL count from INNER JOIN multiple DB tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query returns few row but I want do a count on BCO.[MAIN_ID] so in the final output the column BCO.[MAIN_ID] in each row has a count of users connected with BCO.[MAIN_ID].

```
SELET  CS.[TEST_ID], CS.[TESTGROUP_ID], BCO.[MAIN_ID] as COUNT FROM [DB_01].[dbo].[DS_TABLE] as CS 
LEFT JOIN 
[DB_02].[dbo].[C_TABLE] as BCO on CS.[TEST_ID] = BCO.[TEST_ID]
LEFT JOIN
[DB_02].[dbo].[CR_TABLE] as FOO on BCO.[UID] = FOO.[UID]
```

I tested count when using a single DB and it works fine. But when using multiple DB like here it doesn't work.

If I try the count then I get a error.

```
SELET  CS.[TEST_ID], CS.[TESTGROUP_ID], count(BCO.[MAIN_ID]) as COUNT FROM [DB_01].[dbo].[DS_TABLE] as CS 
LEFT JOIN 
[DB_02].[dbo].[C_TABLE] as BCO on CS.[TEST_ID] = BCO.[TEST_ID]
LEFT JOIN
[DB_02].[dbo].[CR_TABLE] as FOO on BCO.[UID] = FOO.[UID]

Column 'DB01.dbo.DS_TABLE.test_id is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause
```

I even tried group_by `group by BCO.[MAIN_ID]`

Comment: The error is very clear, what don't you understand?

Comment: newbie here. That error didn't make sense also I didn't know we could use multiple groupby columns. Can you explain a bit about the error? I  need to learn a bit more group by

Comment: can you answer this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60866383/mysql-left-join-with-the-result-of-another-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  CS.[TEST_ID], CS.[TESTGROUP_ID], count(BCO.[MAIN_ID]) as COUNT
FROM [DB_01].[dbo].[DS_TABLE] CS LEFT JOIN 
     [DB_02].[dbo].[C_TABLE] BCO
     ON CS.[TEST_ID] = BCO.[TEST_ID] LEFT JOIN
     [DB_02].[dbo].[CR_TABLE] as FOO
     ON BCO.[UID] = FOO.[UID]
GROUP BY CS.[TEST_ID], CS.[TESTGROUP_ID];
```

Comment: can you answer this? It is derived from this answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60866383/mysql-left-join-with-the-result-of-another-join