# SQL LEFT JOIN with the result of another JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm unable to find a way to get the correct result. I think the right way is to join QUERY 1 with QUERY 4 and then do a count to get the correct result, but I'm not sure how to do that.

The count in the last query, first row shows a value of 3, but it should be 2. And second and third row should **not** be considered online so its count should be zero.

What is the step I'm missing that could join the queries the correct way? Any suggestion would help.

Query: 1

```
SELECT  CS.[TEST_ID] as TEST_ID , CS.[TESTGROUP_ID] as TESTGROUP_ID, com1, com2, com3 FROM [DB_01].[dbo].[DS_TABLE] as CS 

TEST_ID | TESTGROUP_ID | com1 | com2 | com3

1111    | 01_1111      | null | null | null
2222    | 02_2222      | null | -2   | null   
3333    | 03_3333      | null | -1   | null 
4444    | 04_4444      | null | -1   | null
```

Query: 2

```
SELECT BCO.[TEST_ID] as TEST_ID, BCO.[USER_ID] as USER_ID FROM [DB_02].[dbo].[C_TABLE] 

TEST_ID | MAIN_ID

1111    | 1234                    - (user not active but his entry is stuck)
1111    | 2345
2222    | 5345                    - (user not active but his entry is stuck)
3333    | 6323                    - (user not active but his entry is stuck)
4444    | 2839
1111    | 1825
```

Query: 3

```
SELECT FOO.[USER_ID], xyz1 from [DB_02].[dbo].[USERS_ONLINE_TABLE]

USER_ID | xyz1

2345    | ---
2839    | ---
1825    | ---
```

Query: 4

```
SELECT BCO.[TEST_ID] as TEST_ID, BCO.[USER_ID] as USER_ID FROM [DB_02].[dbo].[C_TABLE] as BCO 
INNER JOIN
[DB_02].[dbo].[USERS_ONLINE_TABLE] as FOO on BCO.[USER_ID] = FOO.[USER_ID]

TEST_ID | MAIN_ID

1111    | 2345
1111    | 1825
4444    | 2839
```

QUERY: 5

```
SELET  CS.[TEST_ID] as TEST_ID, CS.[TESTGROUP_ID] as TESTGROUP_ID, com1, com2, com3 count(BCO.[USER_ID]) as COUNT FROM [DB_01].[dbo].[DS_TABLE] as CS 
LEFT JOIN 
[DB_02].[dbo].[C_TABLE] as BCO on CS.[TEST_ID] = BCO.[TEST_ID]
LEFT JOIN
[DB_02].[dbo].[CR_TABLE] as FOO on BCO.[UID] = FOO.[UID] 
GROUP BY CS.[TEST_ID], CS.[TESTGROUP_ID], com1, com2, com3 

TEST_ID | TESTGROUP_ID | com1 | com2 | com3 | COUNT

1111    | 01_1111      | null | null | null | 3
2222    | 02_2222      | null | -2   | null | 1
3333    | 03_1111      | null | -1   | null | 1
4444    | 04_4444      | null | null | null | 1
```

But the result I needed was

```
TEST_ID | TESTGROUP_ID | com1 | com2 | com3 | COUNT

1111    | 01_1111      | null | null | null | 2
2222    | 02_2222      | null | -2   | null | 0
3333    | 03_1111      | null | -1   | null | 0
4444    | 04_4444      | null | null | null | 1
```

Comment: mysql is not sqlserver please tag correctly (this like your last question) is sqlserver.

Comment: Where does this `04_4444` come from?

Comment: those are just ID's which can be set for TEST_ID. So TEST_ID 1111 can have TESTGROUP_ID 01_1111 and TEST_ID 2222 can also have TESTGROUP_ID 01_1111. Can't do anything with that.. They are just something to associate with TEST_ID

Comment: Yes, but `04_4444` is nowhere in your tables, so how come it's in your results?

Comment: sorry it got omitted from query 1.  Added it now. Also updated query  5 result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `04_4444` in your last result row has me confused, but I *think* this is just a typo and should be null and you are looking for a full outer join. For the lookup whether a `MAIN_ID` is in the `users_online_table` use `IN`.

```
select
  coalesce(ds.test_id, c.test_id) as test_id,
  ds.testgroup_id, ds.com1, ds.com2, ds.com3,
  coalesce(c.cnt, 0) as [count]
from from db_01.dbo.ds_table ds
full outer join 
(
  select test_id, count(*) as cnt
  from db_02.dbo.c_table
  where main_id in (select user_id from db_02.dbo.users_online_table)
  group by test_id
) c on c.test_id = ds.test_id
order by test_id;
```

Comment: As you have updated your request with a ds_table entry for 4444 | 04_4444, I suppose a mere left outer join may already meet your request. That means you can probably replace `full outer join` by `left outer join`and `coalesce(ds.test_id, c.test_id) as test_id,` by `ds.test_id,`. This might also speed up the query.

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that you can just use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT CS.[TEST_ID] as TEST_ID, CS.[TESTGROUP_ID] as TESTGROUP_ID, com1, com2, com3,
      COUNT(DISTINCT BCO.[USER_ID]) as COUNT
FROM [DB_01].[dbo].[DS_TABLE] CS LEFT JOIN 
     [DB_02].[dbo].[C_TABLE] BCO 
     ON CS.[TEST_ID] = BCO.[TEST_ID] LEFT JOIN
     [DB_02].[dbo].[CR_TABLE] FOO 
     ON BCO.[UID] = FOO.[UID] 
GROUP BY CS.[TEST_ID], CS.[TESTGROUP_ID], com1, com2, com3 ;
```

Comment: I updated the query 5 result a bit. That is how exactly it is right now